# How to create window split for the current tab?

Tags: vimscript

As title. Say I have three splits `top`, `middle`, `bottom`. I want to create a new split from the `bottom`(so the result will be `top`, `middle`, `bottom`, `new_bottom`), even if my current is at either `top` or `middle`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want `:botright new <filename>` or simply `:botright new` for creating an empty buffer.

```
:bo[tright] {cmd}
                Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window,
                it will appear at the bottom and occupy the full width of the
                Vim window.  When the split is vertical the window appears at
                the far right and occupies the full height of the Vim window.
                Doesn't work for :execute and :normal.
```

Comment: Instead of `:botright new <file>`, more likely `:botright [v]split <file-or-buffer>`

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: Technically `:new <file>` is documented as equivalent to `:split`, so no; the only difference is in my head when I think about what I'm doing